# how to compare two strings in pandas large dataframe (python3.x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two DFs from 2 excel files.

1st file(awcProjectMaster)(1500 records)

```
projectCode    projectName
  100101       kupwara
  100102       kalaroos
  100103       tangdar
```

2nd file(village master)(more than 10 million records)

```
villageCode    villageName
   425638          wara
   783651          tangdur
   986321          kalaroo
```

I need to compare the projectName and villageName along with the percentage match.
The following code works fine but it is slow. How can I do the same thing in a more efficient way.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\awcProjectMaster.xlsx")
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\prjToVillageStateWise\\stCodeVillage1To6.xlsx")


def compare(prjCode, prjName, stCode, stName, dCode, dName, sdCode, sdName, vCode, vName):
    with open(r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\prjToVillageStateWise\\stCodeVillage1To6.txt", "a") as f:
        percentMatch = 0
        vLen = len(vName)
        prjLen = len(prjName)
        if vLen > prjLen:
            if vName.find(prjName) != -1:
                percentMatch = (prjLen / vLen) * 100
                f.write(prjCode + "," + prjName + "," + vCode + "," + vName + "," + str(round(percentMatch)) + "," + stCode + "," + stName + "," + dCode + "," + dName + sdCode + "," + sdName + "\n")
            else:
                res = 0
                # print(res)
        elif prjLen >= vLen:
            if prjName.find(vName) != -1:
                percentMatch = (vLen / prjLen) * 100
                f.write(prjCode + "," + prjName + "," + vCode + "," + vName + "," + str(round(percentMatch)) + "," + stCode + "," + stName + "," + dCode + "," + dName + sdCode + "," + sdName + "\n")
            else:
                res = 0
                # print(res)
    f.close()


for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for idxv, r in df1.iterrows():
        compare(
            str(row["ProjectCode"]),
            row["ProjectName"].lower(),
            str(r["StateCensusCode"]),
            r["StateName"],
            str(r["DistrictCode"]),
            r["DistrictName"],
            str(r["SubDistrictCode"]),
            r["SubDistrictNameInEnglish"],
            str(r["VillageCode"]),
            r["VillageNameInEnglish"].lower(),
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distance metric for the strings isn't too accurate, but if it works for you, fine. (You may want to look into other options like the builtin `difflib`, or the Python-Levenshtein module, though.)

If you really do need to compare 1,500 x 10,000,000 records pairwise, things are bound to take some time, but there are a couple things that we can do pretty easily to speed things up:

- open the log file only once; there's overhead, sometimes significant, in that
- refactor your comparison function into a separate unit, then apply the `lru_cache()` memoization decorator to make sure each pair is compared only once, and the subsequent result is cached in memory. (In addition, see how we sort the `vName`/`prjName` pair – since the actual order of the two strings doesn't matter, we end up with half the cache size.)

Then for general cleanliness,

- use the `csv` module for streaming CSV into a file (the output format is slightly different than with your code, but you can change this with the `dialect` parameter to `csv.writer()`).

Hope this helps!

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from functools import lru_cache
import csv

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\awcProjectMaster.xlsx")
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\prjToVillageStateWise\\stCodeVillage1To6.xlsx")

log_file = open(r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\prjToVillageStateWise\\stCodeVillage1To6.txt", "a")
log_writer = csv.writer(log_file)


@lru_cache()
def compare_vname_prjname(vName, prjName):
    vLen = len(vName)
    prjLen = len(prjName)
    if vLen > prjLen:
        if vName.find(prjName) != -1:
            return (prjLen / vLen) * 100
    elif prjLen >= vLen:
        if prjName.find(vName) != -1:
            return (vLen / prjLen) * 100
    return None


def compare(prjCode, prjName, stCode, stName, dCode, dName, sdCode, sdName, vCode, vName):
    # help the cache decorator out by halving the number of possible pairs:
    vName, prjName = sorted([vName, prjName])
    percent_match = compare_vname_prjname(vName, prjName)
    if percent_match is None:  # No match
        return False
    log_writer.writerow(
        [
            prjCode,
            prjName,
            vCode,
            vName,
            round(percent_match),
            stCode,
            stName,
            dCode,
            dName + sdCode,
            sdName,
        ]
    )
    return True


for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for idxv, r in df1.iterrows():
        compare(
            str(row["ProjectCode"]),
            row["ProjectName"].lower(),
            str(r["StateCensusCode"]),
            r["StateName"],
            str(r["DistrictCode"]),
            r["DistrictName"],
            str(r["SubDistrictCode"]),
            r["SubDistrictNameInEnglish"],
            str(r["VillageCode"]),
            r["VillageNameInEnglish"].lower(),
        )
```

Comment: @jezrael Good to know. I'm not a Pandas expert by any means – that was in the original code.

Comment: I know, only in my opinion convert excel to csv and loop by csv module should be here better

Comment: @AKX I will try it out tomorrow. thanks..will get back on this.

Comment: This is good but I want to try out difflib as @AKX suggested.